# Count different column based on values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements

I've the below Student table with marks range of each student. 
Each student can have marks range for more than one subject but not necessary all.

```
Id | Maths | Science | History | Economics
 1 | 25-50 |         |         |          
 2 |       |  50-75  |         |          
 3 |       |         |  0-25   |          
 1 |       |         |         |  > 90  
 4 |       |         |         |          
 2 |       |         |  50-75  |          
 4 |       |  50-75  |         |          
 1 |75-100 |         |         |          
 3 |       |         |         |  30-60 
 1 |       |  50-75  |         |
```

> Range for Maths , Science, History is `[0-25, 25-50, 50-75, 75-100]`
>   and for Economics it is `[0-30, 30-60, 60-90, >90]`

I need a query which will return me 4 columns and all range values for each subject with count of Distinct Ids

```
Subject  | Range | count
Maths    | 0-25  |   1  
Maths    | 25-50 |   0 
Maths    | 50-75 |   0  
Maths    |75-100 |   1  
Science  | 0-25  |   0  
Science  | 25-50 |   0 
Science  | 50-75 |   3  
Science  |75-100 |   0 
History  | 0-25  |   1  
History  | 25-50 |   0 
History  | 50-75 |   1  
History  |75-100 |   0 
Economics| 0-30  |   0
Economics| 30-60 |   1
Economics| 60-90 |   0
Economics|  > 90 |   1
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unpivot the data:

```
select x.subject, x.range, count(distinct t.id)
from the_table
  cross join lateral ( 
    values 
       (maths, 'Maths'), (science, 'Science'), (history, 'History'), (economics, 'Economics')
  ) as x(range, subject)
where range is not null
group by x.subject, x.range;
```

The `values` clause generates one row for each column of the base table. The result has two columns named `range` and `subject`

Comment: Getting this error : There is a column named "maths" in table "student", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.